# loop over multipolygon feature google maps api v 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to loop through a multipolygon feature using google maps v3 to extract each sub polygon and then use [containsLocation()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation) to find out if a location within the sub polygons matches my stored Lat and Long coordinates?

I'm expecting to be able to use a loop like so:

```
//check if multipolygon
if(e.feature.getGeometry().getType()==='MultiPolygon'){

 //loop over sub polygons
  var polygons = e.feature.getGeometry().getArray();

  polygons.foreach(function(item, index){

    //item is our polygon?

    var coords = item.getAt(index).getArray();
    var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({

      paths: coords,

    });

    //check if the subpolygon contains my latlong

    if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(myLatLong, poly)){

     // do something

    }

  });

}
```

However, it doesn't work as I don't think 'item' is actually a polygon?

Any help would be great on how I can achieve this.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data.MultiPolygon

should the var polygons be in an array? I think getArray() returns an array.
polygons.forEach(); instead of [polygons].forEach();

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  You need to make `google.maps.Polygons` from the coordinates, then do the check, so the posted code should in principle work.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: it appears that it loops over the polygons fine, but it's the contains location which never equals true...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue was around the .getAt(i) and it needed to be .getAt(0)

```
if (e.feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'MultiPolygon' ) {
          var array = e.feature.getGeometry().getArray();
          array.forEach(function(item,i){

            var coords= item.getAt(0).getArray();
            var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
              paths: coords
            });
            if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(location, poly)) {
              //do something

            }

          });
        }
```